# replace a string by variable in a file using bash script

Tags: command-line, scripts, text-processing

through bash script, I am trying to find a value-number- from a text in a file,  then make a new variable then replace it with a string in that file
for example. in a file in /root/test.txt , i have a string web1
i need to cut the number "1", and increase it by 1 so it will be 2
then replace web1 by web2
that is what i did so far
any idea how to make it works ?

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
m=grep 'web' /root/test.txt | awk '{print $2}'
i= $m | cut -c3
i=i+1
n='web$i'
$ sed -i 's/$m/$n/g' /root/test.txt
```

Sample input:

```
 project web0
```

Sample output:

```
 project web1
```

Comment: Please post a sample input and a sample output.

Comment: Input In second line in the file test.txt
project web0
output:
project web1

Comment: We'll need to take a look at the input file in order to be able to tell you how to extract the information you want; also personally I'm not really understanding how the output should look like, so an example would help.

Comment: The most fundamental issue with your approach so far is that *shell variables are not expanded when inside single quotes*. However you could do it much cleaner in perl since it can handle arithmetic expressions right in the replacement pattern.

Comment: I didn't notice you edit to your comment. I've added the sample input and sample output you provided to the question. That is easily doable with Perl, but does *any* instance of `webN` have to be replaced with `webN+1` or are there other constraints?

Comment: Yes exactly, I need the script to find the string "webN" in a file and replace it by "webN+1" everytime i run the script

Comment: This could be done with AWK alone, no need for other scripts.  Are `webN` parts always on the second column ?

Comment: yes it is in the second line, second word !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWK can search and replace text as well, so there is no need to use `grep` or `sed`. The code bellow extracts substring from second column (`webN`), increments `N`, and substitutes second field with `webN+1`

```
$ cat testInput.txt                                                                                          
project web0
other
project web1
$ awk '/web/{ num=substr($2,4)+1;$2="web"num };1' testInput.txt                                              
project web1
other
project web2
```

This will print edited file on screen. You can save that to another file like so `awk  [rest of code here] > fileName.txt` and replace original with new using `mv fileName.txt oldFile.txt`

Answer (score 3):

Using Perl:

```bsh
perl -pe 's/\bweb\K[0-9]+\b/$&+1/ge' file
```

To edit the file in place, add the `-i` option:

```bsh
perl -i -pe 's/\bweb\K[0-9]+\b/$&+1/ge' file
```

- `-p`: causes Perl to assume the following loop around your program, which makes it iterate over filename arguments somewhat like sed:

  ```perl
     LINE:
       while (<>) {
           ...             # your program goes here
       } continue {
           print or die "-p destination: $!\n";
       }
  ```
- `-e`: may be used to enter one line of program.
- `s/\bweb\K[0-9]+\b/$&+1/ge`: matches any `web` string preceded by a word boundary, discards the match and matches one or more digits followed by a word boundary, replacing the match with the equivalent number increased by 1.

```
% cat file
project web0
project web1
project web2
% perl -pe 's/\bweb\K[0-9]+\b/$&+1/ge' file
project web1
project web2
project web3
```

Comment: Beaten me by a minute :p +1

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys, I tried this code and that worked fine for me,

```
#!/bin/bash
DPATH="/root/test.txt"
k=$(grep 'web' $DPATH | awk '{print $2}')      # web ends by a number#
i=$(grep 'web' $DPATH | awk '{print $2}'| cut -c3)
m=$((i+1))
n="web$m"
sed -i -e 's/'"$k"'/'"$n"'/g' $DPATH
```